# Can I only show the folder(s) a user has access to in Directory Browsing (IIS8)

Tags: directory-listing, iis8

I'm trying to make Directory browsing a bit more pleasant for a client,

The folder in question is hosted on a Windows 2012 server running IIS8, A website is set up on this, allowing access using Windows Authentication (local users) - (permissions assigned per sub-folder)
The containing folder has a group permission applied containing all users for the sub directories)

So everyone can go to the URL, enter their credentials and see the entire list of subfolders, and can then only access their own.

Is it possible to only show the sub folder(s) for which they have access?

Answer (score 1):

Since your using authorization you should be attempting to hide the folders or files on the operating system rather than IIS. This will prevent people seeing folders they don't have access too. This can be done with [Access-based Enumeration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), a similar question can be found on [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/482195/active-directory-only-show-accessible-shares). It is also possible to hide folders using an [advanced NTFS setup](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm).